# Use of Stack function or Explode Function to achieve the hive result

Tags: regex, hive

```
Select col1 from staging   returns the following 

"a, b,u,y"

"c, d"

e

f
```

I wanted the following result instead (remove the double quotes, and split the individual record by commas and then stack them)

```
a
b
u
y
c
d
e
f
```

The way I try to achieve this is

select distinct(regexp_replace(col1,'"','')) from staging

This will take care of removing the double quotes.

I think this is what should work but there is something missing ..

```
select distinct(explode(split(col1,",")))  from staging
```

What Im trying is to split the column values by providing , as a splitter , which will return an Array. After that, use explode to split the array into Rows.

Im sure that the RegX to mention a comma is incorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1
FROM (
  SELECT
    explode(split(regexp_replace(col1, "\\s|\"", ''), ',')) AS col1
  FROM staging
) t;
```

`DISTINCT` seems to be implicitly implemented in Hive as a UDTF, and there is a limitation (at least as of 0.13.0 which is what I'm using) on nesting UDTFs in expressions (`explode` is a UDTF).

This is what this query returned with your posted sample data:

```
hive> DESCRIBE staging;
OK
col1                        string                              
Time taken: 0.295 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> SELECT * FROM staging;
OK
"a, b,u,y"
"c, d"
e
f
Time taken: 0.208 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
hive> SELECT DISTINCT col1
    > FROM (
    >   SELECT
    >     explode(split(regexp_replace(col1, "\\s|\"", ''), ',')) AS col1
    >   FROM staging
    > ) t;
...
... Lots of MapReduce-related spam
...
a
b
c
d
e
f
u
y
Time taken: 19.787 seconds, Fetched: 8 row(s)
```

If you don't want or need the DISTINCT (which implicitly lex-sorts the results as you can see), then you could use just the inner portion of the query:

```
SELECT
  explode(split(regexp_replace(col1, "\\s|\"", ''), ',')) AS col1
FROM staging;
```

Which would then return something like:

```
a
b
u
y
c
d
e
f
Time taken: 14.479 seconds, Fetched: 8 row(s)
```

Comment: Thanks rchang ...I tried this and it also works but Im sure there is something wrong ..    select distinct col1 from (
        select  explode(split(regexp_replace(col1,'"',''),"," )) as col1  from staging
        ) as T     .... this gives me the results and the regex is different

Comment: @Vaya The difference between our regular expressions is that yours eradicates quotation marks while mine eradicates both quotation marks and white space.  As a result, when I run the query with your regex, ` b` and ` d` have leading spaces (due to the white spaces from the original input text).